# Insert space character before a certain character

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file which looks like this:

```
120E+00 360E+01 258E-09-784E+02  
-847E+00-360E+01 242E-08 420E+05  
14E+00 360E+01 254E+00 78E+02  
-120E+00-254E-01-223E-09-786E-02
```

E+00,E+01,E-01 etc are in scientific notation meaning ^0,^1,^-1 etc.

I would like to obtain the file in the following format:

```
120E+00 360E+01 258E-09 -784E+02  
-847E+00 -360E+01 242E-08 420E+05  
14E+00 360E+01 254E+00 78E+02  
-120E+00 -254E-01 -223E-09 -786E-02
```

I want to add a space before the negative numbers, without modifying the scientific notation, or the negative number itself.
I also don't want to add a space if the negative number is the first one in the line (first column), just from column 2 to the end of the line.
I would also like to use awk.

I hope my explanation is clear.
Thank you!

Comment: by the way, do fix whatever software wrote these numbers, or at least leave a bug report somewhere :)

Comment: Hmm. Can you have lines where a long number and a positive number are back-to-back? I.e. something like `-847E+00360E+01 ...` (the first number on the second line and the second number on the first line in your example). Your example doesn't show any such, but if the issue is that the field width is somehow limited, then it might be possible. And would make parsing that more annoying.

Comment: (I was trying to think if there's a C printf format (or combination of) that would produce those, but I can't tell what it would be. Some of the fields, e.g. all at the start of the lines look left-aligned; but some look right-aligned, like the third and fourth fields on the second and fourth lines.)

Comment: No, it can't look like -847E+00360E+01. The problem is only related to that minus sign.

Comment: This format is part of a standard format for GNSS (GPS) Navigation Files. This is how the processing software will compute and display them, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, essentially, you want to add a space before every `-` if the character immediately before the `-` is a number. You can do that in `awk` but it really isn't a good choice here. It is far simpler to do it with `sed`:

```
$ sed -E 's/([0-9])-/\1 -/g' file
120E+00 360E+01 258E-09 -784E+02  
-847E+00 -360E+01 242E-08 420E+05  
14E+00 360E+01 254E+00 78E+02  
-120E+00 -254E-01 -223E-09 -786E-02
```

Or Perl:

```
$ perl -pe 's/([0-9])-/\1 -/g' file
120E+00 360E+01 258E-09 -784E+02  
-847E+00 -360E+01 242E-08 420E+05  
14E+00 360E+01 254E+00 78E+02  
-120E+00 -254E-01 -223E-09 -786E-02
```

For both of the above, add `-i` if you want to modify the original file instead of printing it out:

```
sed -i -E 's/([0-9])-/\1 -/g' file
perl -i -pe 's/([0-9])-/\1 -/g' file
```

And here's a way to do it in GNU `awk` any modern version of `mawk` and any other `awk` that supports `gensub`, courtesy of [Ed Morton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/133219/ed-morton) who provided this in a now deleted comment:

```
awk '{print gensub(/([0-9])-/,"\\1 -","g")}' file
```

With GNU `awk` (`gawk`), you can use `-i inplace` to edt the original file:

```
gawk -i inplace '{print gensub(/([0-9])-/,"\\1 -","g")}' file
```

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, I added it to the answer.

Comment: Where can one find a version of `mawk` that supports `gensub()`?

Comment: @EdMorton, I believe Stéphane's question is for you.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I don't have any idea, I was just blindly reproducing Ed's comment, but I have yet to see him be wrong on anything related to awk. His original comment simply mentioned "modern versions of `mawk`".

Comment: @EdMorton, which `mawk` would that be? AFAICT, ThomasDickey's mawk-1.3.4-20200120 which is the most *modern* `mawk` I know of doesn't support gawk's `gensub()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed -e "s/-[0-9]*E/ &/g" -e "s/^ -/-/g" file
```

output

```
120E+00 360E+01 258E-09 -784E+02  
-847E+00 -360E+01 242E-08 420E+05  
14E+00 360E+01 254E+00 78E+02  
-120E+00 -254E-01 -223E-09 -786E-02
```

Answer (score 0):

you absolutely don't need so-called "modern" variants of awk to get it done :

```
mawk 'gsub("[0-9][-]","&"_)gsub("."_," -")\
        sub("[\t ]+$", "")_'     \_='\3\21' file0.txt           

120E+00 360E+01 258E-09 -784E+02
-847E+00 -360E+01 242E-08 420E+05
14E+00 360E+01 254E+00 78E+02
-120E+00 -254E-01 -223E-09 -786E-02
```

Confirmed to work on gawk, mawk-1, mawk-2, and nawk.

For the simpler vairant that also fixes trailing spaces/tabs, as well as accounting for variations in scientific notation :

```
mawk2 'gsub("[-][0-9]*[Ee][+-]?"," &")/-(NF=NF)<!_'
```